# Delphi 2007 IDE layout modified after a crash

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I loaded a bad PAS/DFM file (long story), which caused a GPF, after which the IDE crashed horribly. Lost my Project-related data (list of open files, etc).

Now, when I start the IDE, it always is in "run" mode. that is, it shows the breakpoints and watches and local variables, even though no program is running. Similarly, the properties are not visible unless I use F11 to bring them up. I've restarted the IDE repeatedly. Interestingly, it still can compile and run a program.

How do I reset the IDE so that it works properly?

Comment: ugh, sorry about that, in Delphi IDE layout denoted by term *desktop*, so: **"run mode" == debug desktop**, meaning debug desktop became a default desktop

Answer (score 9):

Check your layout.  It's a combo box on the toolbar.  It's probably set to 'Debug Layout' instead of Default or Classic (or something else if you've setup a custom layout.)

Comment: +1 This does sound like an issue with the desktop layout. If your solution doesn't work, there's also deleting the `project.dsk` folder - although I'd probably just rename it to something other than `.dsk` - and then restart the IDE.

Comment: I must have been tired and confused - deleted confused comment.